# http download file name

Tags: http

May i know how to assign a file-name to a a-href file download.

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/couch/getFile?dbName=xxx&file=test.xml">get-file</a>
```

On right-clicking and Save as: A services running on the background will return test.xml contents and the user can save it locally. But here everytime user needs to type a filename for saving. Instead i'm thinking to pull the test.xml. May i know how to tell the browser to use "test.xml" as a download file name?

Will setting headers on HTTP response would work? if so may i know how we can do that?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to append the HTTP response header "Content-Disposition"

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName +"\"");
```

Comment: Note that IE seems to treat the single quotes as part of the file name.

Comment: Single quotes are not valid for the filename. See [`quoted-string`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html)

Comment: I replaced the single quotes.

Comment: If `filename` contains quotes or backslashes (allowed on UNIX), this will break, as those needs to be escaped.

Comment: Quoted pairs (escaping) cannot be used because it breaks existing software. Instead, escape " as `%22` and keep backslash as ```\``` because that is the de-facto standard followed by all existing software. For instance, if you upload a file named ```foo"bar\```, the browser sends `filename="foo%22bar\"` (tested with Firefox and Chrome on Mac in 2019). If you try to follow the RFC and treat `\"` as an escape sequence, parsing fails.

Answer (score 40):

The HTTP header [`Content-Disposition`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4) allows you to suggest a file name.

> The Content-Disposition response header field […] can be used to attach
> additional metadata, such as the filename to use when saving the
> response payload locally.

If you look at the [BNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.1) you'll see that the filename is specified as a [`quoted-string`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html):

> quoted-string  = ( <"> *(qdtext | quoted-pair ) <"> )

This would be a valid example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Please note that single quotes `'` are not valid. If you need to include quotes (") in your filename you can use ". However [RFC-6266 suggests to avoid including quotes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#appendix-D):

> Avoid including the "" character in the quoted-string form of the
> filename parameter, as escaping is not implemented by some user
> agents, and "" can be considered an illegal path character.

Comment: For quoted-string, how do you escape quotes in the filename?

Comment: `quoted-pair` is "\" CHAR, whereas CHAR contains ". So \" will do that. The RFC says that also in its BNF: The backslash character ("\") MAY be used as a single-character quoting mechanism only within quoted-string

Comment: The updated [RFC-6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#appendix-D) suggests: Avoid including the "\" character in the quoted-string form of the       filename parameter, as escaping is not implemented by some user       agents, and "\" can be considered an illegal path character.

Comment: If you don't want the browser to force a download, which is what I understand the OP to be requesting, then use "inline" instead of "attachment"
    `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="fname.ext"`

Answer (score 11):

In modern browsers you can also use download attribute on link tag:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/couch/getFile?dbName=xxx&file=test.xml" download="test.xml">
    get-file
</a>
```

You can check it's support on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Answer (score 1):

To set UTF-8 filenames for specific languages like UA, DE, RU etc.

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename*=UTF-8'en'an%20example
```

Documentation:

- https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-content-disp-02.xml
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

There is an interesting sample:
https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/master/src/AbstractCsv.php

```php
protected function sendHeaders(string $filename): void
{
    if (strlen($filename) !== strcspn($filename, '\\/')) {
        throw InvalidArgument::dueToInvalidHeaderFilename($filename);
    }

    $flag = FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW;
    if (strlen($filename) !== mb_strlen($filename)) {
        $flag |= FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH;
    }

    /** @var string $filtered_name */
    $filtered_name = filter_var($filename, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, $flag);
    $filename_fallback = str_replace('%', '', $filtered_name);

    $disposition = sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', str_replace('"', '\\"', $filename_fallback));
    if ($filename !== $filename_fallback) {
        $disposition .= sprintf("; filename*=utf-8''%s", rawurlencode($filename));
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: '.$disposition);
}
```