# MVC Post Form, but optionally return download or content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, download, return

So I have a form action, that uploads a document and process it...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection col)
    {}
```

But I want to either return and download (NOT A LINK) but rather the download just starts, OR some html content to show the user on the page.

What should I return, and do I need to change the attribute ( HttpPost ) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you can put in your Action-Method.

```
        bool shouldDownload = true;

        if (shouldDownload)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=guitars_11.jpg");
            return File(@"c:\Temp\guitars_11.jpg", "image/jpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
```

The [HttpPost] attribute can stay - it only has an affect on routing (if the request is a POST request, the action will be invoked). It has no influence on what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately whether you deliver an HTML page or file back to the browser it's all just HTTP.

You need only set the content-type http response header to the proper mime type for the file, and optionally set the content-disposition header to set the filename ( [http download file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307499/http-download-file-name)).